# Excel report using access db (~2gb) as backend substitutable by R with shiny or markdown?

Tags: r, excel, ms-access, shiny, r-markdown

I currently have an Access database which pulls data from an Oracle for various countries and is currently around 1.3 GB. However, more countries and dimensions should be added, which will further increase its size. My estimate would be around 2 GB, hence the title. 
Per country, there is one table. These tables are then linked in a second Access db, where the user can select a country through a form which pulls the data from the respective linked table in Access db1, aggregates it by month, and writes it into a table. This table is then queried from Excel and some graphs are displayed. 
Also, there is another form where the user can select certain keys, such as business area, and split the data by this. This can be pulled into a second sheet in the same excel file.

The users would not only want to be able to filter and group by more keys, but also be able to customize the period of time for which data is displayed more freely, such as from day xx to day yy aggregated by week or month (currently, only month-wise starting from the first of each month is supported).

Since the current Access-Access-Excel solution seems to me to be quite a cumbersome one, I was wondering whether I might make the extensions required by the users of this report using R and either shiny or markdown. I know that shiny does not allow files larger than 30MB to be uploaded but I would plan on using it offline. I was just not able to find a file size limit for this - or do the same restrictions apply?

I know some R and I think that the data aggregations needed could be done very fast using dplyr. The problem is that the users do not, so the report needs to be highly customizable while requiring no technical knowledge. Since I have no preexisting knowledge of shiny or markdown, I was wondering whether it was worth going through the trouble of learning one enough to implement this report in them.

Would what I want to do be feasible in shiny or R markdown? If so, would it still load quickly enough to be usable?

Comment: Whether it is worth to convert to Shiny/Rmarkdown depends on your time budget, but it is certainly technically feasible. For performance, you might want to try testing some of your queries using R and see how long it takes for each query to complete. Just Google `R Access database` and you can find lots of code examples.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood me, @warmoverflow. The goal is to substitute the Access backend by R, not to pull the tables from Access into R. Ideally, I'd want to run the queries from the database and create some data frames. Then, I'd like to access the information from these dataframes via a form from shiny or markdown. For example, the user should select a country from a list, and then that information is loaded. Is that possible? Or would I have to query the information from the database every time an item on the shiny/markdown is selected?

Comment: You should be able to preload the tables into dataframes, though an issue is that how big the data frames will be and if you have enough memory to handle them. You can run this code at the startup of your app (see http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html, section `Objects visible across all sessions`).

Comment: thank you @warmoverflow ! I ended up querying the data into RDS files and loading the RDS file before the server function, as described in the article you linked to.